# Read XML file using SimpleXML throws Serializer Exception

Tags: java, exception, deserialization, simple-framework

I use SimpleXML to save a simple POJO into XML file and then read it back. I follow [this](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#deserialize) tutorial. The file is successfully created, but the reading part is just simply not working. It throws the second exception which comes from `serializer.read`.

```
Room room = new Room("1");

Serializer serializer = new Persister();
try {
    File ff = new File("room.xml");
    serializer.write(room, ff);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("FileNotFoundException\n");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception from serializer.write\n");
}

try {
    File ffi = new File("room.xml");
    Room aroom = serializer.read(Room.class, ffi);
    System.out.println("RoomName: " + aroom.getRid() + "\n");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("FileNotFoundException\n");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception from serializer.read\n");
}
```

Any hint?

Comment: and the exception is.. ?

Comment: You ask us to detect why an exception is thrown without giving us the message and type of the exception. Replace "System.out...e by "e.printStackTrace()", and give us the stack trace it produces, or at least the beginning of it.

Comment: Also useful would be the source of Room and the contents of room.xml

Comment: Okay, something strange happened. I've been working on this since yesterday, but it never occurred to me that commenting both the `System.out.println` for the serializer part solves the problem! *scratching head*

Comment: Sorry! After playing around, I found out where the mistake is. I replace the default constructor with the one taking param, so when I assign `serializer.read`, the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a default constructor in `Room`.

```
public Room(){
}
```

Alternatively, make sure your constructor looks like this:

```
public Room(@Attribute(name="rid") String rid){
    this.rid = rid;
}
```

Comment: Yes, just found it out myself. No default constructor in my class.